# How to parse below .txt file?

Tags: python, csv, io

```
|2014|,|H0AK00097|,|N00032846|,|John Cox (R)|,|R|,|AK01|,|    |,| |,|Y|,|C|,|RL|,| |
```

I am reading above line in a `.txt` file by below code.

```
with open("E:\campaign_finance\CampaignFin14\cands14.txt", "r+") as f:
         data = list(csv.reader(f))
```

Is there a way to read this line by also removing `|`.

Comment: Side-note: Use [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings) for Windows paths (and never end them in a backslash; build paths with `os.path.join` and you won't need trailing backslashes anyway). Sure, `"E:\campaign_finance\CampaignFin14\cands14.txt"` works fine. But you'll be unpleasantly surprised when a path component begins with, for example, `a` (`\a` is ASCII Bell character), `b` (ASCII backspace), `r` (ASCII carriage return), `n` (ASCII line feed), etc., and Python interprets it as the escape code. Raw strings (string literal prefixed w/`r`) save you.

Comment: It is not exactly pipe separated, but you can parse it as csv that use pipe as the quote character.  There is a module for it. For details see the duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tweaking the dialect settings on the `reader` initialization should do it. From what your data looks like, it would probably be:

```
csv.reader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, quotechar='|')
```

It's possible you may need to tweak other settings, e.g. `doublequote`, `escapechar`, etc., depending on whether vertical pipes can appear in fields, and if so, how they should be escaped. You can read the [formatting parameters documentation for more info](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters).